# Query Parameters in Express being extracted?

Tags: node.js, curl, express, request, applescript

I'm writing an API in Node.JS for an AppleScript application. The AppleScript application runs `curl` in a shell script in this form:

```
do shell script ("cd " & quoted form of myDir & "
curl http://localhost:5000/server.properties?some-value=true&next-value=something%20else&[...] -O")
```

It's intended to download a file called `server.properties` into the directory `myDir` with content based on the specified parameters, but for some reason when Express receives the request, it displays only this when I run `console.log(res.originalUrl)`:

```
/server.properties?some-value=true
```

And it treats the request as if none of the other parameters are specified. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or how to figure out where it's going wrong?

**EDIT** It turns out to be the way I ran the shell script. The URL needs to be quoted so that the `&` doesn't act as an operator in the shell script.

Comment: Have you tried outputting quotes around the URL? The `&` is an operator in most shells and may be breaking up the command.

Comment: Oh! That might be it, let me check.

Comment: That seems to be the problem. I used the key phrase ``quoted form of`` in AppleScript and everything sent just great! Make the answer and I'll add it as the correct one.

Comment: Yes I know. I had mistyped what my original code was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was the following:

```
do shell script ("cd " & quoted form of myDir & "
curl " & quoted form of (myUrl & myQuery) & " -O")
```

Where `myUrl` is set to `"http://localhost:5000/server.properties"` and `myQuery` is set to `"?some-value=true&next-value=something%20else&[...]"`.